# Dynamically creating iframe content

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm currently using extJS4 for the userinterface in a Zend Framework 1.9 application.
Currently I'm in the process of creating a popup where I want to show specific data, depending
on the data the page calling the iframe has.

I've got as far as creating the iframe when I click on the appropriate button

```
 upWin=new Ext.Window({
        title : "iframe",
        width : 300,
        height: 300,
        layout : 'fit',
        items : [{
            xtype : "component",
            autoEl : {
                tag : "iframe",
                src : "<?= $this->baseUrl("/mytest.php")?>"
            }
        }]
        });
    upWin.show();
```

My question here is how I could transfer the needed content/data into it. I don't want to use the GET paramter there if possible so is there any other option to do this?
(examples of the data I need in the mytest.php are id's and title text, .... so that I don't need a new .php page for each variant where I use this iframe).

EDIT:
To formulate it a bit more clearly...the get parameters or URL parameters are a thing I don't want to use if possible (thus I don't want to use /mytest.php?param1=value1&param2=value2........ if it is avoidable).

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly send the data you need in your php as parameters in the url (eg. 
mytest.php?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3&.........)

php provides functions in order to access the values of the aforementioned url parameters ...
google it

Comment: Url parameters are the get parameters ($_GET is filled with them in php). And sadly they are just those I don't want to use (I'll edit the maintext so that it is stated clearly there that it is the url parameters I don't want to use). but tnx though